# How to prove the proportionality of a scalene triangle that fits inside another scalene triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm trying to help my son prepare for an exam. I am many years out of school. How can I prove the below proportionality assertion, and explain the solution coherently? Any outside references are welcome, such as YouTube videos, etc. I need to relearn this material too if I am to be of any help.

I *believe* we are dealing with scalene triangles! One nested inside another.

[image]

Comment: Where is the problem coming from? Context is important as it may be related to different topics. Can we get a complete picture of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\vec{HE}=a-b$ and $\vec{HX}=\frac14 \vec{HE}$.

So we have $\vec{DX}=\vec{DH}+\vec{HX}=b+\frac14(a-b)=\frac14a+\frac34b$.

Comment: The point Karl is making is that when you are given that a vector $\vec v$  is a fraction of a different vector $\vec u$, you might be able to compute vector $\vec u$ first. In a similar way, $\vec a +\vec {EG}=9\vec b$. This will allow you to compute $\vec {EG}$ and then $\vec{EF}$ if you need that.